# is there an equivalent to posix_ipc on windows? for python

Tags: python, posix, ipc, shared-memory, pywin32

so I am wandering is there an equivalent to Posix_ipc on windows? what I want is to make an anonymous mapping shared memory between unrelated python processes, I've heard about Win32_ipc but I couldn't find anything for it

Comment: How about https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#module-multiprocessing.shared_memory ?

Comment: thx, but in my application I am traying to make the shared memory from the lowest level as passable, so this is why i am trying to avoid this library on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: It's standard library, why would you avoid it?

Comment: I want to design the internal structure of the shared memory, and the way that the processes write/read to/from the shared memory.

Comment: You can go to town on the [`SharedMemory.buf`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory.buf) memoryview you get...

Comment: oh wait, i can't use objects with it, right?

Comment: It's - it's just a buffer of raw memory that's shared with multiple processes. Sure you can use arbitrary objects if you serialize them into some form.